# TypeScript hasOwnProperty equivalent

Tags: javascript, object, typescript, typescript1.8

In JavaScript, if I want to loop through a dictionary and set properties of another dictionary, I'd use something like this:

```
for (let key in dict) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = dict[key];
  }
}
```

If `obj` is a TypeScript object (instance of a class), is there a way to perform the same operation?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> If obj is a TypeScript object (instance of a class), is there a way to perform the same operation?

Your JavaScript is valid TypeScript ([more](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/getting-started/why-typescript)). So you can use the same code as it is.

Here is an example:

```
class Foo{
    foo = 123
}

const dict = new Foo();
const obj = {} as Foo;

for (let key in dict) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = dict[key];
  }
}
```

Note: I would recommend `Object.keys(obj).forEach(k=>` even for JavaScript, but that is not the question you are asking here.

Comment: I have a side question about this; in your case you initialize the foo property, which ensures that it is present in the generated js code; although if the property is not defined, then it's not part of the generated code at all. Do you know why that is? This surprised me a bit when I tried using hasOwnProperty on some instance and got false back although I expected it to be present but undefined.

Comment: Let's consider that undefined properties i.e. all properties that are defined in the typescript `class A { prop1:string, prop2:number}` will not be enumerated by any of `Object.keys` or `this.hasOwnProperty(k)` since the autogen javascript has no knowledge of those properties.

Comment: Why would you recommend `Object.keys(obj).forEach(k=>` over `for()` ?

Answer (score 6):

## ECMAScript 2022 update:

Use [Object.hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

More info: [ECMAScript 2022 language specification, 13th edition, June 2022](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.hasown)

Answer (score 1):

I found fp-ts `has` function worked best for my use case:

```
const role = 'mother' as string
const rolesConst = {
  mother: 'mother',
  father: 'father'
} as const
if (has(role, rolesConst)) {
  // role's type is 'mother' | 'father'
}
```

https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/ReadonlyRecord.ts.html#has

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015)'s [`Object.assign(obj, dict);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

[TypeScript's spread operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) comes to mind, but I don't think it's applicable because that's for creating a new object, you want to overwrite properties in an existing *class*.

Things to be aware of is it is only a shallow copy, and it will invoke setters in the target class if they exist.