# I want to list all public properties of a Class/Interface

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript we can define classes and their public properties. How can I get a list of all public properties defined for a class.

```
class Car {
    model: string;
}

let car:Car = new Car();
Object.keys(car) === [];
```

Is there a way to make Car emit its `model` property?

Comment: This may have been answered already (use `hasOwnProperty`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691858/typescript-hasownproperty-equivalent and the `typeof` operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: At runtime `public` and `private` members look the same, so I don't think it's possible to find the public API like you describe.

Answer (score 4):

Like Aaron already mentioned in the comment above, public and private members look the same in Javascript, so there cannot be a method that distinguishes between them. For instance, the following TypeScript Code

```
class Car {
    public model: string;
    private brand: string;

    public constructor(model:string , brand: string){
        this.model = model;
        this.brand = brand;
    }
};
```

is compiled to:

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(model, brand) {
        this.model = model;
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    return Car;
}());
;
```

As you can see, in the compiled JavaScript Version, there is absolutely no difference between the members `model` and `brand`, event though one of them is private and the other one is public.

You could distinguish between private and public members by using some naming convention (For instance, `public_member` and `__private_member`).

Answer (score -4):

Updated answer (also see Crane Weirdo's answer on final JS public/private, which my answer doesn't address):

```
class Vehicle {
    axelcount: number;
    doorcount: number;

    constructor(axelcount: number, doorcount: number) {
        this.axelcount = axelcount;
        this.doorcount = doorcount;
    }

    getDoorCount(): number {
        return this.doorcount;
    }
}

class Trunk extends Vehicle {
    make: string;
    model: string;

    constructor() {
        super(6, 4);
        this.make = undefined; // forces property to have a value
    }

    getMakeAndModel(): string {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let car:Trunk = new Trunk();
car.model = "F-150";

for (let key in car) {
  if (car.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof key !== 'function') {
      console.log(key + " is a public property.");
  } else {
      console.log(key + " is not a public property.");
  }

}
```

Output:

```
axelcount is a public property.
doorcount is a public property.
make is a public property.
model is a public property.
constructor is not a public property.
getMakeAndModel is not a public property.
getDoorCount is not a public property.
```

Previous answer:

```
class Car {
    model: string;
}

let car:Car = new Car();

for (let key in car) {
  // only get properties for this class that are not functions 
  if (car.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof key !== 'function') {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong. The type of `key` is never going to be 'function', and `hasOwnProperty` will exclude properties inherited from the prototype. It also doesn’t include declared but undefined properties, and doesn’t exclude private or protected properties.